# Can't able to match Greater than sign in preg_match in PHP

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

Below is my example used to match the input. But it won't match at all but when i add this regex in the http://www.phpliveregex.com/ it returning the result. I dont know what i made wrong. Please point me the problem

```
$input_lines = "$this->Lang['TEST']";    
preg_match_all("/\$this->Lang\[\'(.*?)\'\]/", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

Expected Result:

```
array(2
    0   =>  array(1
           0    =>  $this->Lang['TEST']
    ),
    1   =>  array(1
           0    =>  TEST
    )
)
```

Comment: Please check my answer and if it works for you, please accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` symbol inside a double quoted string literal is followed with `this` and PHP tries to interpolate it to a known variable - that was not declared. Use single quoted literal to avoid string interpolation with the regex:

```
$input_lines = "\$this->Lang['TEST']";    
preg_match_all('/\$this->Lang\[\'(.*?)\'\]/', $input_lines, $output_array);
print_r( $output_array);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/0UkLAB)

Comment: @shyammtp This answer seems correct.  Please award it the green tick or leave a comment that explains what is not quite right about it.